# Is there a way to concatenate multiple rows into one rows keeping same dataset format in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How in sqlserver do I go from this:

[image]

to this :

[image]

**PRECISION : "123" and "456" are chars data types, no numerical values**

Many thanks...

Regards,

Comment: This doesn't look like concatenation; where did the `0`'s go? But you could just use `MAX` for the above, though I doubt that is the *real* solution as I suspect you haven't given us the full picture..

Comment: Can you post the table schema you are querying to get this dataset? You are likely going to want to do some kind of groupby but exactly what will depend on how the data is structured.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUM ( [January] ) AS [January],
    SUM ( [February] ) AS [February]
FROM MyTable;
```

This SUMs the value for each column specified. Without more details, there is no telling if additional grouping is needed, but it does sum your column values for a resultset--assuming that is your intent, and not looking for MAX, etc.

Comment: Hi, it was as simple as that. Results came from a subquery returned by a case when, and I didn't notice I could use this 0 as an int instead of a nvarchar. SELECT MAX() did the job as well.

Comment: Great. Just note that SUM and MAX serve two very different purposes.

Comment: Hi again, how do you manage this use case if "123" and "456" were chars and not numerical values ? Thank you.

Comment: It is okay then. I went throught an outer apply against the same table by selecting only the field that did interest me and shew it on the dataset.
To only show one line, I've selected a TOP 1. That is not brilliant, but it does the job actually...

Comment: @whats_wrong Sorry for the delayed reply, I've been busy. I don't fully understand your need so using `TOP` may or may not be right for you. To answer your question: *how do you manage this use case if "123" and "456" were chars and not numerical values?* If you know the values will **always** be numeric (which begs the question why isn't the column's data-type) you can cast the values as the int data-type like so: `SUM ( CAST ( [January] AS int ) ) AS [January]`.